# Is it possible to include custom C++\WinRT UWP controls in WPF with XAML Islands and WindowsXamlHost?

Tags: wpf, uwp, c++-winrt

I have a WPF application that is too onerous to rewrite wholesale in UWP. Some of the UWP controls would utilize `SwapChainPanel` and thus have C++/WinRT to manage DirectX. To determine the feasibility of implementing portions of the application in UWP and including them in WPF, I made a [minimal sample app](https://github.com/dcwork/UiPermutations) following [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands) that attempts to compose UWP controls in a WPF application targeting .NET Core 3.1.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppCore3._1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xh="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost"
        Title="WPF App"
        Height="500"
        Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <xh:WindowsXamlHost InitialTypeName="UwpLib.ManagedGrid"
                            Height="225" />
        <xh:WindowsXamlHost InitialTypeName="UwpLibNative.NativeGrid"
                            Height="225" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This works great for a managed control like [`UwpLib.ManagedGrid`](https://github.com/dcwork/UiPermutations/blob/main/UwpLib/ManagedGrid.cs) but [`UwpLibNative.NativeGrid`](https://github.com/dcwork/UiPermutations/blob/main/UwpLibNative/NativeGrid.h) does not load:

[image]

The debugger shows an exception:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 'Bad IL format.'
```

That exception indicated to me a build configuration issue, but I *think* the application is set up correctly in that regard. Is this just not possible with XAML Islands today or have I made some configuration mistake in the sample app?

**Update 1:**

I discovered the ["Windows Desktop Compatible" option](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/a-reference-cannot-be-added-because-the-two-projec/1128228#T-N1312049) and made sure that was set to "Yes". No change.

Comment: Two things: 1) I think `BadImageFormat` is a 32 vs 64 bit issue 2) Yes you can inject arbitrary Window (UWP, DX12, etc) into a WPF project (and likely into an UWP project).

Comment: Did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands ?

Comment: @Soleil Yes I actually got to the microsoft link in my post via the URL you mentioned. Yes  `BadImageFormat` does indicate a bitness mismatch but as I said I think have the build configuration correct (maybe I missed something?).

Comment: Try to check the dependencies with depends or cleanup and rebuild; also there might be a copy that is not cleaned up, so maybe try some powershell cleanup.